# Select receiver of form based on hidden value

Tags: forms, typo3

I use Typo3 10LTS with the default form extension. I want to select the receiver of the form based on a value in a hidden field.

But of course the hidden field doesn't contain the real email address but only a key value.

Thanks,
Stephan

Comment: Please update your questions with some details, i.e. sample code, to let us understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be possible via [dynamically set finisher values](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/master/en-us/I/Concepts/Variants/Index.html#set-finisher-values-dynamically) based on [formValues conditions](https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-form/master/en-us/I/Concepts/Variants/Index.html#formvalues-array)